# How to create a share link in Buildfire

Tags: buildfire

I'm attempting to create a share link that users within a plugin can send to friends via email or sms. If their friend has the app, the goal would be to open the app to the plugin with a query string similar to navigation.navigateTo does so that it would open to specific content within the plugin. If they don't, the goal would be to send them to the app's webpage where they could download the app from the appropriate store (android or apple). Is this possible or at least a portion of it?

I've generated a share link using buildfire.deeplink.generateUrl but can't find the appropriate steps from there in the API documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, The steps as following:

- generate the  deeplink URL

  `buildfire.deeplink.generateUrl(options, callback)`
- make sure of passing `data` property to options where its representing the
  deep link data that developers need to provide to the plugin once the user
  opened the share link. For more information on how to reed this data from
  plugin, see [buildfrire.deeplink.getData](https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/deep-links#getdata).

  ```
     buildfire.deeplink.generateUrl(
      {
        data: { videoId: "9Q-4sZF0_CE" },
      },
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        } else {
          console.log(result.url);
        }
      }
    );
  ```
- after generate the deep link use the following function to open share device options

  `buildfire.device.share({ link: deepLinkUrl }, callback);`
- Finally you have to handle deeplink data in you plugin to be able to open desired content based deeplink data that you pass during generate the deeplink URL, check this [buildfrire.deeplink.getData](https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/deep-links#getdata).
- For more details [check the doc](https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/share-links-and-deep-linking/#generateurl).

**Example**

```
// share function
const share = () => {
  let deeplinOptions= {};
  deeplinOptions.title = 'Hello world';
  deeplinOptions.type = "website";
  deeplinOptions.description = 'First program';
  deeplinOptions.imageUrl = '<IMAGE URL>';

  deeplinOptions.data = {
    "link": vidId
  };

  buildfire.deeplink.generateUrl(deeplinOptions, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      let options = {
        link: result.url
      };
      let callback = function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.warn(err);
        };
      };

      buildfire.device.share(options, callback);
    };
   });
 };
```

```
// Handle Deeplink data in your plugin 
const handleDeepLinkData = () => {
  buildfire.deeplink.getData(function (data) {
    if (data && data.link) {
      let vidId= data.link;
      
      // Do what you want
    }
    // Do what you want
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad Al Rawashdah
The second portion of what I'm looking to achieve is for recipients who DO NOT have the app installed. In this scenario, they would be directed to a download page in the appropriate app store or a web page for the app where they could then navigate to the appropriate store for their device. Is this a default action / response to the generated URL or is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, it is a default action, generated URL will take care

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, Just share the result URL